# How to start the Ubuntu for arm through U-boot?

Tags: server, arm

How to start the Ubuntu for arm through U-boot? I have a firmware support only U-boot.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! If you want specific answers, [edit] your question to specify your hardware!

Answer (score 3):

There is not a universal guide for installing ARM and with U-boot since the hardware manufacturers in general want to keep their hardware closed. So how difficult his becomes depends totally on the hardware and the manufacturer of that hardware.

See the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/arm64/index.html) section [5.1](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/armhf/ch05s01.html) has a generic method for identifying and adjusting settings when you need to use u-boot but do read section 3.7 too:

1st part of 3.7:

> **3.7.1. Systems with U-Boot firmware**
>
> As already mentioned before, there is unfortunately no standard for system firmware on ARM systems. Even the behaviour of different systems which use nominally the same firmware can be quite different. This results from the fact that a large part of the devices using the ARM architecture are embedded systems, for which the manufacturers usually build heavily customized firmware versions and include device-specific patches. Unfortunately the manufacturers often do not submit their changes and extensions back to the mainline firmware developers, so their changes are not integrated into newer versions of the original firmware.
>
> As a result even newly sold systems often use a firmware that is based on a years-old manufacturer-modified version of a firmware whose mainline codebase has evolved a lot further in the meantime and offers additional features or shows different behaviour in certain aspects. In addition to that, the naming of onboard devices is not consistent between different manufacturer-modified versions of the same firmware, therefore it is nearly impossible to provide usable product-independend instructions for ARM-based systems.

In case you do have a system that is known section 5.1.3.1 details how to do this. There are general guidelines though and you will likely need to adjust for your specific case.

> 5.1.3.1. TFTP-booting in U-Boot
>
> Network booting on systems using the U-Boot firmware consists of three steps:
>
> - a) configuring the network,
> - b) loading the images (kernel/initial ramdisk/dtb) into memory
> - c) actually executing the previously loaded code.
>
> First you have to configure the network, either automatically via DHCP by running

```
setenv autoload no
dhcp
```

> or manually by setting several environment variables

```
setenv ipaddr <ip address of the client>
setenv netmask <netmask>
setenv serverip <ip address of the tftp server>
setenv dnsip <ip address of the nameserver>
setenv gatewayip <ip address of the default gateway>
```

> If you prefer, you can make these settings permanent by running

```
saveenv
```

> Afterwards you need to load the images (kernel/initial ramdisk/dtb) into memory. This is done with the tftpboot command, which has to be provided with the address at which the image shall be stored in memory. Unfortunately the memory map can vary from system to system, so there is no general rule which addresses can be used for this.
>
> On some systems, U-Boot predefines a set of environment variables with suitable load addresses: kernel_addr_r, ramdisk_addr_r and fdt_addr_r. You can check whether they are defined by running

```
printenv kernel_addr_r ramdisk_addr_r fdt_addr_r
```

> If they are not defined, you have to check your system's documentation for appropriate values and set them manually. For systems based on Allwinner SunXi SOCs (e.g. the Allwinner A10, architecture name “sun4i” or the Allwinner A20, architecture name

```
“sun7i”), you can e.g. use the follwing values:

setenv kernel_addr_r 0x46000000
setenv fdt_addr_r 0x47000000
setenv ramdisk_addr_r 0x48000000
```

> When the load addresses are defined, you can load the images into memory from the previously defined tftp server with

```
tftpboot ${kernel_addr_r} <filename of the kernel image>
tftpboot ${fdt_addr_r} <filename of the dtb>
tftpboot ${ramdisk_addr_r} <filename of the initial ramdisk image>
```

> The third part is setting the kernel commandline and actually executing the loaded code. U-Boot passes the content of the “bootargs” environment variable as commandline to the kernel, so any parameters for the kernel and the installer - such as the console device (see Section 5.3.1, “Boot console”) or preseeding options (see Section 5.3.2, “Ubuntu Installer Parameters” and Appendix B, Automating the installation using preseeding) - can be set with a command like

```
setenv bootargs console=ttyS0,115200 rootwait panic=10
```

> The exact command to execute the previously loaded code depends on the image format used. With uImage/uInitrd, the command is

```
bootm ${kernel_addr_r} ${ramdisk_addr_r} ${fdt_addr_r}
```

> and with native Linux images it is

```
bootz ${kernel_addr_r} ${ramdisk_addr_r}:${filesize} ${fdt_addr_r}
```

> Note: When booting standard linux images, it is important to load the initial ramdisk image after the kernel and the dtb as U-Boot sets the filesize variable to the size of the last file loaded and the bootz command requires the size of the ramdisk image to work correctly. In case of booting a platform-specific kernel, i.e. a kernel without device-tree, simply omit the ${fdt_addr_r} parameter.

Comment: I don't really understand. I just want to build a Ubuntu for arm environment, but my firmware only supports u-boot mode. Is there a process-based installation tutorial?

Comment: No there is not. -every- arm manufacturer uses their own specifications and even use different specification with their own newer hardware.  You will be largely on your own getting Ubuntu onto it.